# Sets: why slice category is not isomorphic to functor category

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, category-theory

Is known that the slice category $\mathbb{Set}/I$ is equivalent to the category of $I$-indexed sets $\mathbb{Set}^{I}$. We can establish two functors

$$\varphi: \mathbb{Set}^{I} \rightarrow \mathbb{Set}/I$$
$$\psi: \mathbb{Set}/I \rightarrow \mathbb{Set}^{I}$$

by

1. $\varphi \left( \left( A_{i}  \right)_{i \in I}  \right) \mapsto \pi_{A}: \oplus_{i \in I} A_{i} \rightarrow I $, where $\oplus$ stands for the disjoint union and $\pi$ is the indexing projection, and
2. $\psi \left( \pi: A \rightarrow I \right) \mapsto \oplus_{i \in I} \{ \pi^{-1}(i) \} $.

It is then easy to show the equivalence $ \mathbb{1}_{ \mathbb{Set}/I } \simeq \varphi \psi, \mathbb{1}_{ \mathbb{Set}^{I} } \simeq \psi \varphi $.

But I cannot see how these functors are not essentially the inverses of each other. The operations seem to be completely reversible and we get exactly the original result after applying $\psi \varphi$ or $\varphi \psi$.

I could not come up with a counterexample. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: They are "essentially" inverse, but not on the nose because the construction involves taking coproducts. Test it out on a simple finite set.

Comment: I did. I can't wrap my head around it. Seriously :) maybe it sounds stupid, but I can't see it. Both functors don't "lose the data" -- everything works out perfect in both directions. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I mean, isomorphisms dont lose structure. So if you want to think of them as essentially the same, I think you can move on. But Martin's post is correct.

Comment: Exactly, and it seems to me that all the structure is preserved. I could show an example with finite sets here, but it would have taken too much place and it's obvious anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that the disjoint union of sets is usually constructed as $\coprod_i A_i = \bigcup A_i \times \{i\}$, but other constructions are also available. If $A$ is a set with a map $A \to I$ and fibers $A_i$ for $i \in I$, then $A$ is not necessarily *equal* to that disjoint union $\coprod_i A_i$; rather we have a canonical isomorphism $\coprod_i A_i \to A$. This shows that $\phi \psi$ is isomorphic, but not equal to the identity. Probably we can remedy this by constructing $\coprod_i A_i$ as $\bigcup_i A_i$ if the sets $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint, and otherwise as $\bigcup_i A_i \times \{i\}$. But still, in the other direction, if we have a family of sets $(A_i)_{i \in I}$, then the fiber of $\coprod_i A_i \to I$ will be $A_i \times \{i\}$ and only equals $A_i$ if the given family of sets is pairwise disjoint. As you can see, these details really belong to set theory and have no "categorical content". See also [principle of equivalence](http://ncatlab.org:8080/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Martin. But is it true that every finite set is unambiguously decomposable into the disjoint union? I have a feeling that for finite sets these two functors really give the identity.

Comment: No. Please read my question again, and recall the notions of "internal disjoint union", "external disjoint union".

Comment: Sorry to comment a question this old, but it didn't seem the case to ask a new one, that would be almost a duplicate. I'd just want to ask why on Mac Lane & Moerdijk's _Sheaves in Geometry and Logic_ it is said precisely that the equivalence $\mathbf{Set}/I\simeq \mathbf{Set}^I$ is not an isomorphism because  $\varphi\psi$ is not the identity (at the beginning of page 29). It seems that $\psi\varphi$ instead is the identity, but I don't see how it is possible:

Comment: defining $\coprod A_i$ as $\bigcup A_i\times\{i\}$ neither $\psi\varphi$ or $\varphi\psi$ are the identity; defining $\coprod A_i$ as $\bigcup A_i$ when the $A_i$ are disjoint, then $\varphi\psi$ is the identity and $\psi\varphi$ is not. If we assume that the  sets of a family are automatically disjoint (that  I don't know how much legit is), then we'd actually have an isomorphism of categories. So what definition is used in the book to obtain that  combination?